# SPI to soft UART

Tags: hardware, c, uart, spi

Is there a way to use the SPI on pi for UART communications without any external hardware?

Is there a library in C for this?

Comment: See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24019/can-the-gpios-pins-be-used-as-another-rx-and-tx/24035#24035 especially @joan 's answer. Maybe the mentioned library is helpful.

Comment: I have written many 'bit-bang' communication protocol drivers using only GPIO pins.  In general, this means timing is VERY important and interrupts must be disabled so no unexpected delays occur.  It often also means counting the execution time of every instruction involved in the protocol driver.  If you find a ready made drive, you should use it rather than rolling your own driver